# Summing values of function whose input is in a certain interval, MATLAB

Tags: matlab

The heading might be slightly confusing, but what I want to do is the following:

I have function inputs x,t, outputs y (i.e y = f(x,t)), and a set of ranges xr, tr and I want to do

```
v = zeros(1,length(xr)-1)
for kk=1:(length(xr)-1)
   ix = x >= xr(kk) & x < xr(kk+1) & t >= tr(kk) & t < tr(kk+1)
   v(kk) = sum(y(ix));
end
```

This is very slow, while histc, which does almost the same (except it sums the number of entries in the interval instead of the function output) is very fast. How can this be implemented faster? I tried using arrayfun, but this only gave a 25% increas in speed.

Thanks,

Comment: What is the typical length of `x` and `xr`?

Comment: xr ~ 2000 elements, x,y 1 500 000 elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `histc` with two output arguments, the second output will give you the bin numbers for each data entry. You can use the bin numbers to sum up the entries belonging to each bin, for instance, using `bsxfun` or `accumarray`.

```
[val, id] = histc(x, xr); 

v = accumarray(id(:), y(:));
```

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for the answer, but can this be made more generalized? What I actually want is (my data is parametrized by two values)

v = zeros(1,length(xr)-1)
for kk=1:(length(xr)-1)
   ix = x >= xr(kk) & x < xr(kk+1) & t >= tr(kk) & t <= tr(kk+1)
   v(kk) = sum(y(ix));
end

Comment: @user2090149 I think this answer actually does what you want, give it a try.

Comment: @user2090149 You are aware that your request is not a generalization but a whole different question? Since I doubt that `histc` can be used with two different `edges` arguments at the same time, my answer is probably not a valid solution for this request.

Comment: Ok, sorry, then it is a whole different question. But your answer was valid for the original question. But do you know a trick to speed up this? I know histc is built in function and it will be difficult to get the same performance in a pure matlab implementation, but i feel my implementation must be naive.